# PostgreSQL Query with many:many join is very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, sequelize.js

Problem: I need to find Posts with a specified Hashtag. The many:many join table is called PostHashtag. However, it looks like the inner joins are too slow:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
    "Post"."id",
    "Post"."createdAt",
    "Post"."photo",
    "Post"."thumbnail",
    "hashtags->PostHashtag"."id" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.id",
    "hashtags->PostHashtag"."hashtagId" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.hashtagId",
    "hashtags->PostHashtag"."postId" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.postId",
    "hashtags->PostHashtag"."createdAt" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.createdAt",
    "hashtags->PostHashtag"."updatedAt" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.updatedAt"
FROM
    "Posts" AS "Post"
INNER JOIN (
    "PostHashtags" AS "hashtags->PostHashtag"
    INNER JOIN "Hashtags" AS "hashtags" ON "hashtags"."id" = "hashtags->PostHashtag"."hashtagId"
) ON "Post"."id" = "hashtags->PostHashtag"."postId"
AND "hashtags"."name" = 'pumpupfam'
WHERE
    "Post"."photo" IS NOT NULL
AND "Post"."private" IS NULL
ORDER BY
    "Post"."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 90;
```

yields

```
Limit  (cost=2651.58..2651.60 rows=7 width=212) (actual time=349.987..350.048 rows=90 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2651.58..2651.60 rows=7 width=212) (actual time=349.985..350.013 rows=90 loops=1)
        Sort Key: "Post"."createdAt"
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 48kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=18.80..2651.49 rows=7 width=212) (actual time=9.125..336.449 rows=30092 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=18.37..2623.52 rows=19 width=28) (actual time=9.096..93.508 rows=31495 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using hashtags_name_unique_index on "Hashtags" hashtags  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.034..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'pumpupfam'::text)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "PostHashtags" "hashtags->PostHashtag"  (cost=17.94..2607.97 rows=711 width=28) (actual time=9.059..79.563 rows=31495 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: ("hashtagId" = hashtags.id)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=21507
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on posthashtags_hashtagid_fk_index  (cost=0.00..17.77 rows=711 width=0) (actual time=5.393..5.393 rows=31496 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ("hashtagId" = hashtags.id)
              ->  Index Scan using "Posts_pkey" on "Posts" "Post"  (cost=0.43..1.46 rows=1 width=184) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=31495)
                    Index Cond: (id = "hashtags->PostHashtag"."postId")
                    Filter: ((photo IS NOT NULL) AND (private IS NULL))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 0
Planning time: 2.865 ms
Execution time: 350.289 ms
```

How can I speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: Subquery must have an alias.

Comment: @wildplasser there is no subquery there.  That is a parenthesized join, which doesn't need an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be an index on "Post"."createdAt" which it can walk backwards, looking up rows in the other tables as needed, until it accumulates 90.  Then you would also need indexes on "hashtags->PostHashtag"."postId" and hashtags.id.

> ```
> ->  Nested Loop  (cost=18.80..2651.49 rows=7 width=212) (actual time=9.125..336.449 rows=30092 loops=1)
> ```

However, given the above misestimation, it might be hard to get it to use this method.  You can `set enable_sort=off` to test if my preferred method is even possible (it should be if you have the correct indexes), and is actually an improvement.

Comment: I already have an index for `"Post"."createdAt" DESC NULLS FIRST` which isn't being used, it seems.

Comment: @Garrett will it use it if you `set enable_sort=off`?  If so, is it actually faster?

Comment: No change off or on

Answer (score 0):

The performance killer is the outer nested loop join, and the cause are the misestimates on the inner nested loop join and the index scan on `PostHashtags`.

It is not easy to fix the skew added by the inner nested loop, but maybe it is good enough to improve the estimate on the index scan to tip the scales:

```
ANALYZE "PostHashtags";
```

If that fixes the misestimate, tune that table so that autoanalyze processes it more often.

Otherwise, try

```
SET default_statistics_target = 1000;
ANALYZE "PostHashtags";
```

and see if that improves the estimate on the index scan.

If that fixes the misestimate,

```
ALTER TABLE "PostHashtags"
 ALTER "hashtagId" SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

Comment: There was no change in the estimate after analyzing

Comment: Also no change with `default_statistics_target = 10000`? That would indeed be surprising.

Comment: Could you clarify why it's a misestimation? I'm seeing `->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "PostHashtags" "hashtags->PostHashtag"  (cost=17.94..2607.97 rows=711 width=28) (actual time=9.059..79.563 rows=31495 loops=1)` which has a high cost but a high time as well, so it looks right to me.

Comment: Oh, I should have explained. I'm talking about the row count: 711 estimated vs. 31495 actual. That's the cause of the problem. Is that a very large table, so that even a statistics resolution of 10000 cannot produce a better estimate?

Comment: I'm not sure, still reading up on these database terms, but we have about 15M Posts and 5M PostHashtags.

Comment: That's not large. Increasing the statistics for the column and a following `ANALYZE` should definitely improve the estimate.